# Make some of the query parameters dependent in RAML

Tags: api, raml

I am writing an api spec with RAML. I have a GET api with three query parameters. One of them is optional. In the case of other two, one of them should be present at least. How do I define this in the api spec

```
/api
description: api end point

queryParameters:
  field1:
    description: field1
    required: false
    type: string
  field2:
    description: field2
    required: false
    type: string
  field3:
    description: field3
    required: false
    type: string
```

Here field1 is completely optional. It is ok if we don't have it. But out of the other two, either field2 or field3 should be present.

So the api call should be

```
/api?field2=value or /api?field3=value
```

How do I do this in raml?

Comment: I don´t think there is away to do this with RAML. The best away is to considir this a semantic problem and handle this in your application returning a 409 HTTP Status Code.

Answer (score 3):

You can split the query params in two types (one for every combination) and use a union type:

```
types:
  oneParam:
    properties:
      field1:
        description: field1
        required: false
        type: string
      field3:
        description: field3
        type: string
  otherParam:
    properties:
      field1:
        description: field1
        required: false
        type: string
      field2:
        description: field2
        type: string

/api:
  description: api end point

  get:
    queryParameters:
      type: oneParam | otherParam
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force so that the bad request is returned in case of no parameter is passed, then you can try to use `minProperties`:

```
{types:
  oneParam:
    **minProperties: 1**
    properties:
      field1:
        description: field1
        required: false
        type: string
      field3:
        description: field3
        type: string
  otherParam:
    **minProperties: 1**
    properties:
      field1:
        description: field1
        required: false
        type: string
      field2:
        description: field2
        type: string

/api:
  description: api end point

  get:
    queryParameters:
      type: oneParam | otherParam
}
```